# Is k8s a good idea to run a simple application?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am tring to use Docker to hold my blog website. But before coding, I know the k8s from the web.

I am totally green with web, so it confused me that is it a good idea to hold my blog in k8s? The infometion from web tell me that `k8s > Docker`. I do not know is it a really a good idea or not? I have try to learn the k8s for 2 days, and know what is the cluster, services and pods and so on. But it sound not make my work easy...

Should I go on to learn the k8s or it is just a bad idea and I should turn around to just learn how to learn Docker?

Thanks.

Comment: Deploying your blog on kubernetes is like this: https://twitter.com/dexhorthy/status/856639005462417409

Comment: I find that the overhead of managing a Kubernetes instance is far greater than simply using a Docker host. But that is just my opinion and merely a consequence of me using Docker since the earlier days. Still Kubernetes has some features that I really miss on Docker, namely Secrets, easier ingress support, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your need for high availability and performance for your blog and how many machines you are willing to use to host your blog.

What I read from your "new-ness" to the web you do not need to go there yet. Docker is probably enough for.

First get familiar with docker / containers and then with K8S.

If you also want to learn Docker this might be a good resource (https://docker-from-scratch.ivonet.nl/) ... shameless plug